Issues Migrating from Elastic Search 6.8 to AWS OpenSearch Service 1.3 in a Blue-Green Deployment
I'm currently working on upgrading a legacy system from Elastic Search 6.8 to AWS OpenSearch Service 1.3. The system functions as an analytics layer, processing data from various sources. Below is a brief overview of the setup:
Data Ingestion and Processing: We ingest data from multiple sources, store it in Oracle, and process it using an EMR cluster via Spark. After the ETL process, the data is loaded into Elastic Search and indexed.
Infrastructure and Deployment: We employ a daily blue-green deployment strategy. Each day, we build new EMR and Elastic Search clusters using a CloudFormation template as soon as the jobs are initiated. Once the new cluster is successfully built and loaded, the DNS is switched to the new cluster, and the old cluster is deleted.
The Issue:
We followed the AWS documentation for migrating from Elastic Search to AWS OpenSearch. Given our daily cluster rebuilding process, we assumed that updating the CloudFormation template and running our jobs would suffice. However, we are encountering an issue where data fails to load during this process, and the logs provide minimal information.
Details:
We have two indexes, each with its own template.
Each template contains only one mapping type, labeled "person".
We attempted to change the mapping type from "person" to "_doc" as recommended, but the issue persists.
Question:
Are there specific considerations when migrating from Elastic Search to AWS OpenSearch in a daily blue-green deployment environment?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

After some troubleshooting, we were able to resolve the issue with migrating from Elastic Search 6.8 to AWS OpenSearch 1.3 in our daily blue-green deployment setup.
Solution:
Update CloudFormation Template:
We updated the CloudFormation template to reflect the OpenSearch 1.3 domain configuration.
Address Bulk Operation Errors:

After making the updates, we encountered an error: Could not write all
entries for bulk operation [1119/1119].

This issue was related to the index templates and mapping types.
Index Template Changes:
We updated our index templates where the mapping type was previously person to _doc as required by OpenSearch 1.x.
Additionally, we added the following settings to the index:
"index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true to handle any malformed data gracefully.
We also set the include_type_name=true condition when creating the index to ensure compatibility with the existing data structure.
After making these changes, everything started working as expected. Our data loads successfully, and the clusters operate smoothly in the new environment.
I hope this helps anyone else who might encounter similar issues during their migration process!
